# Reference Error when using ROT13 cipher to obfuscate email

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, referenceerror, rot13

I'm using [this online tool](http://rot13.florianbersier.com/) to create the `JavaScript` code required to obfuscate an email address with an `ROT13 cipher` and it works fine, however I get the below JS `ReferenceError` when using it:

```
ReferenceError: eo is not defined
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
<span id="obf">
    <script>document.getElementById("obf").innerHTML="<n uers=\"znvygb:vasb@zzjgenqrznexf.pbz.nh\" >vasb@zzjgenqrznexf.pbz.nh</n>".replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(c){return String.fromCharCode((c<="Z"?90:122)>=(c=c.charCodeAt(0)+13)?c:c-26);});document.body.appendChild(eo);</script>
    <noscript>[Enable JavaScript to see email]</noscript>
</span>
```

This bit of code at the end of the script appears to be the culprit:

```
document.body.appendChild(eo);
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: Is this all the code? Is `eo` mentioned anywhere else?

Comment: @SimonVerbeke Yes, this is all the code given to me from that tool. I just replaced the code that was inside the `<noscript>` to something more custom.

Comment: That's very odd. It would seem to be an error on their part. I'm not sure where they expect `eo` to come from.

Comment: This code just doesn't work. It seems like you could just omit the part `document.body.appendChild(eo);` see plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JwOnSVOGnehBtRrZBhOx?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ... the last part of the script is just plain wrong:

```
<span id="obf">
    <script>document.getElementById("obf").innerHTML="<n uers=\"znvygb:vasb@zzjgenqrznexf.pbz.nh\" >vasb@zzjgenqrznexf.pbz.nh</n>".replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(c){return String.fromCharCode((c<="Z"?90:122)>=(c=c.charCodeAt(0)+13)?c:c-26);});</script>
    <noscript>[Enable JavaScript to see email]</noscript>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out his [GitHub](https://github.com/xpressyoo/Email-Obfuscator). It has some more instructions, including that you should first obfuscate the mail though javascript. Like devnull69 mentioned, that last part can be omitted. And it is indeed omitted in the documentation on GitHub.

EDIT: Checking out the HTML of the page, the `eo` object is indeed used for something. Check out [line 58](https://github.com/xpressyoo/Email-Obfuscator/blob/master/obfuscator.html#L58) and [line 144](https://github.com/xpressyoo/Email-Obfuscator/blob/master/obfuscator.html#L144)

Comment: Hmmmm..... interesting. I guess since it's not used in his documentation it doesn't hurt to take it out?